# Blackberry webworks 10 using image from picture taken\uploaded

Tags: blackberry-10, blackberry-webworks

I am stuck with an issue and I have no idea what to try next.

In My application I offer my user a choice to either take a photo or choose a photo from the gallery. This part works fine, the problem arises with the saving\reading of the photo. Lets take this from the camera invoke perspective.

```
function startCameraApp() {
    PhotoTaken = false;
    blackberry.event.addEventListener("onChildCardClosed", sharePhoto);

    blackberry.invoke.invoke({
        target: "sys.camera.card"
    }, onInvokeSuccess, onInvokeError);
}
```

and in sharePhoto I have the following code...

```
function sharePhoto(request) {
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = "file://" + request.data;
    image.onload = function () {
        // Now here I need to read the image file and convert it into base64.
        var resized = resizeMe(image);  // the resizeMe function is given below and it simply makes my image smaller
        var imagedata = resized.split("base64,");
        sessionStorage.setItem("MyNewPicture", imagedata);
    }
}





function resizeMe(img) {

    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    var max_width = 600;
    var max_height = 600;
    var width = img.width;
    var height = img.height;

    // calculate the width and height, constraining the proportions
    if (width > height) {
        if (width > max_width) {
            height = Math.round(height * max_width / width);
            width = max_width;
        }
    } else {
        if (height > max_height) {
            width = Math.round(width * max_height / height);
            height = max_height;
        }
    }

    //resize the canvas and draw the image data into it
    img.width = width;
    img.height = height;
    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;
    canvas.classname += "ui-hidden";
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);
    return canvas.toDataURL();
}
```

So the app runs and it takes the photo and everything seems fine, yet the data uploaded to local storage is simply a blank screen. It works 100% in the blackberry 10 simulator, but not on my device. On the device it saves an empty string.

**Edit**

Ok. So I added this to my function for testing purposes and I am still stuck and I don't know what to do...

```
function sharePhoto(request) {
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = "file://" + request.data;
    image.onload = function () {
        // Now here I need to read the image file and convert it into base64.
        var resized = resizeMe(image);  // the resizeMe function is given below and it     simply makes my image smaller
        var imagedata = resized.split("base64,");

        alert(imagedata); // This returns a blank popup

        sessionStorage.setItem("MyNewPicture", imagedata);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe when you use the split method it returns an array, so you'd access it like this:

```
var resized = resizeMe(image);
var imagedata = resized.split("base64,");
    imagedata = imagedata[1]; // this gives you everything after the 'base64,' string
```

However, the main problem I see is that you're splitting the imagedata string which is removing the whole 'this is an image' prefix from the data.

When you display the imagedata as an image, you need to have the **data:image/jpeg;base64,**
prefix as well.

So that being said, your images source would be

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,<rest of base64 string here>
```

Comment: split does indeed return an array. This was not the reason I got my problem however. I used base64,l as a split such that I can easily retrieve the base64 string. You can See my answer below as to what was causing my problem. Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to include an extra element in my application's config.xml.

```
<access subdomains="true" uri="file://accounts/"></access>
<access subdomains="true" uri="file://accounts/100/shared/camera/"></access>
```

This gives access to your application to these folders and their containting files. Simulator's does not require this permission.